# Sharing a TCP data stream

Tags: sockets, tcp, proxy

I receive a data stream from an sensor by connecting to a TCP port. The data is currently being written to a database, but now I need to make the same data stream available to another application for real time monitoring. The sensor will only allow a single connection so I cannot establish another connection for the 2nd application. Does anyone know of an application that can proxy a TCP connection for multiple sources.

Comment: You can write a simple transmitter to transfer the received data to other applications, using TCP.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a TCP Server socket in your application that accepts connections from other clients. For each data block you receive you send this to all connected clients.

Maybe you have to parse the protocol first and send only complete messages to avoid sending only the second part of a message to a new connected client.